# Troubles with respond.js. IE8 doesn't show common styles

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, media-queries, respond.js

I use CSS media queries on my site. They all look like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:959px) and (min-width:481px) {
    /*some styles */
}
```

To make it work in IE8 I use [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). But it works with some mistakes. 
If I use any common styles which I've never determined in any @media, IE doesn't show them.

```
body {background-color:#ABC;}
```

IE will not show this style if I've been already used any media query where I've determined style for `<body>` tag. So if I want to make previous style common I should write it for all media queries. What's wrong?

Comment: IE8 doesn't support three-digit color values, you need to use full six-digit implementation.

Comment: It's just an example. I use six-digit color values.